# CKEditor Balloon Block Toolbar doesn't work

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to add CKEditor 5 into my project, but something goes wrong. I need the balloon block version. But the block toolbar does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import * as BalloonBlockEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block';
```

```
BalloonBlockEditor
      .create(document.querySelector(`#${this.editorId}`), {
        blockToolbar: [
          'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3',
          '|',
          'bulletedList', 'numberedList',
          '|',
          'blockQuote', 'imageUpload'
        ],
      })
      .then(editor => {
        console.log(editor);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

```
<div [id]="editorId" class="content-text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up two ways of using CKEditor 5 – [directly](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html), and via [Angular integration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html).

If you used it directly, in JavaScript, without Angular, then this will work (mind the changed import):

```
import BalloonBlockEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block';

BalloonBlockEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
    blockToolbar: [
      'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3',
      '|',
      'bulletedList', 'numberedList',
      '|',
      'blockQuote', 'imageUpload'
    ],
  })
  .then(editor => {
    console.log(editor);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

If you want to use it in Angular, then you need to both import and initialize it differently:

```
import * as BalloonBlockEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block';

@Component( {
    ...
} )
export class MyComponent {
    public Editor = BalloonBlockEditor;
    ...
}


<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Read more in the ["Rich text editor component for Angular 2+"](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The problem was with integration: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/css.html